# Rails3 Nested Routes, Update Redirect_To Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get my routing to work properly after I update an invoice.

I have an order with many invoices and the following in my routes.rb

```
resources :orders do
 resources :invoices
end

resources :invoices
```

And in my invoices controller:

```
 def update
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.update_attributes(params[:invoice])
        format.html { redirect_to(invoice_path(@invoice), :notice => 'Invoice was successfully updated.') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
```

I can create an invoice through:

```
/orders/1/invoices/new
```

But when I save or update, I'm sent to:

```
/invoices/1
```

I need to redirect back to the order invoice path:

```
/orders/1/invoices/1
```

Have also tried changing the redirect to:

```
   redirect_to(order_invoice_path(@order, @invoice), :notice => 'Invoice was successfully updated.')
```

This works but it sends me to the wrong url with the order id being the same as invoice id...

Any help appreciated.

-- UPDATE --

If I try the following in my invoices controller, I end up with an error too..

```
 redirect_to(order_invoice_path(@order, @invoice)
```

---

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"invoices", :order_id=>nil, :id=>#<Invoice id: 6, order_id: 17, invoice_id: nil, created_at: "2011-06-26 17:49:01", updated_at: "2011-06-26 17:49:01">}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you do the following in your controller:

```
redirect_to(order_invoice_path(@order, @invoice), :notice => 'Invoice was successfully updated.')
```

But do you set `@order` somewhere?

Whatever, you'd better do:

```
redirect_to(order_invoice_path(@invoice.order, @invoice), :notice => 'Invoice was successfully updated.')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. The latter approach was perfect. Where can I read about this - it's really holding me up - I'm forever stuck trying to figure out out to do such things. Jx

Comment: When you're creating associations between models, this kind of method is builtin: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html